# Differences between generated x509 certificates in kubernetes v1.10.11 and v1.11.5

Tags: kubernetes

I have been creating an amazon AMI with kubernetes installed on it to use as a worker node in EKS, I install the kubelet binary from the amazon-eks s3 bucket.

After upgrading from k8s version 1.10.11 to 1.11.5 I noticed a difference in the x509 certificate that is generated when installing kubelet.

If I jump onto one of the worker nodes with 1.10.11 installed and run this command `openssl s_client -connect localhost:10250 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -text` I get the following output for `X509v3 Subject Alternative Name`:

```
DNS:ip-<my-ip>.eu-central-1.compute.internal, DNS:ip-<my-ip>, IP Address:<my-ip>
```

whereas, if I run the same command on a worker node with 1.11.5 installed I get the following output for `X509v3 Subject Alternative Name`:

```
DNS:ip-<my-ip>
```

The only change between the two nodes is the version of kubernetes installed.

Am I missing anything that is now required as of version 1.11.x to set the additional Subject Alternative Names as seemed to be previously done in v1.10.x? I require the IP address to be set in the certificate in the format `IP Address:<my-ip>` which I was getting for free in version 1.10.

FYI I am running kubelet with the following args:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet \
  --address=0.0.0.0 \
  --authentication-token-webhook \
  --authorization-mode=Webhook \
  --allow-privileged=true \
  --cloud-provider=aws \
  --cluster-dns=DNS_CLUSTER_IP \
  --cluster-domain=cluster.local \
  --cni-bin-dir=/opt/cni/bin \
  --cni-conf-dir=/etc/cni/net.d \
  --container-runtime=docker \
  --max-pods=MAX_PODS \
  --node-ip=INTERNAL_IP \
  --network-plugin=cni \
  --pod-infra-container-image=602401143452.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com/eks/pause-amd64:3.1 \
  --cgroup-driver=cgroupfs \
  --register-node=true \
  --kubeconfig=/var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig \
  --feature-gates=RotateKubeletServerCertificate=true \
  --anonymous-auth=false \
  --client-ca-file=CLIENT_CA_FILE \
  --node-labels=env=NODE_LABEL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as handling the certificates there are not Kubernetes specific differences between `1.10.11` and `1.11.5`. It might be related to specific [EKS AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/eks-optimized-ami.html) for the nodes that you are using (make sure they are matching)

If not you can manually [create](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/certificates/) the certificates for the kubelet using the same CA as the one in your Kubernetes master. For example:

***easyrsa***

```
./easyrsa --subject-alt-name="IP:${MASTER_IP},"\
"IP:-<my-ip>,"\
"DNS:ip-<my-ip>.eu-central-1.compute.internal,"\
"DNS:ip-<my-ip>,"\
--days=10000 \
build-server-full server nopass
```

***openssl***

Config (csr.conf):

```
[ req ]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn

[ dn ]
C = <country>
ST = <state>
L = <city>
O = <organization>
OU = <organization unit>
CN = <my-ip>

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = ip-<my-ip>.eu-central-1.compute.internal
DNS.2 = ip-<my-ip>
IP.1 = <my-ip>

[ v3_ext ]
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer:always
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage=keyEncipherment,dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage=serverAuth,clientAuth
subjectAltName=@alt_names
```

Create CSR:

```
$ openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr -config csr.conf
```

Create certificate:

```
$ openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA cluster-ca.crt -CAkey cluster-ca.key \
-CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 10000 \
-extensions v3_ext -extfile csr.conf
```

***cfssl***

In a similar fashion you can use [cfssl](https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl), described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/certificates/#cfssl).